# Terminate bash function called by another bash function without terminating caller

Tags: bash

I have a bash function `func_1` which calls `func_2`. `func_2` does not terminate until told to via ^C. How can I terminate `func_2` and then continue execution of `func_1`?  Calling `func_1` and then terminating during `func_2` stops `func_1`. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to kill a function as such, you'll have to kill whatever `func_2` is doing from a `trap` or the surrounding code. If you include the actual code it would be easier to see what would actually work.

Comment: Also, on another, unrelated note, `^C` is equivalent of `SIGINT` (i.e. `kill -2`). `SIGTERM` is `kill -15`.

Comment: bash functions run in the same process as the script that calls them. and signals like `^C` (`SIGINT`) are delivered at the process level. So, there is no way to terminate the current function without terminating the parent script. Having said that, you could `TRAP` the signals set some global variable and do an early exit from `func_2` by detecting that variable. It will help us if you post `func_2`'s  code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the processing in func_2 is done with external program (see sleep statement in example below), you can use 'trap' to capture the ctrl/C (actually SIGINT, as per comments above from @anishsane)

Note that explicit termination of the external process is performed by dispatching the signal to that child.

```
#! /bin/bash

func_1() {
        echo "In func_1"
        sleep 100 &
        # Save the PID of the external program
        X=$!
        trap 'kill -INT $X' INT
        # Wait for the external program to finish/get killed.
        wait
        echo "resume func_1"
}

func_2() {
        echo "In func_2"
        func_1
        echo "resume func_2"
}

func_2
```

If you can the above script, and enter "ctrl/C", the output will be:

```
In func_2
In func_1
^Cresume func_1
resume func_2
```